# Storing data with Eloquent Model not working, Call to undefined method

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-resource

I want to make Restful API with Laravel and I want to write a script that is going through the CSV file, and firstly POST Animal, then get Animal ID from response, and POST AnimalDate, but It's not working as I want and I'm getting  this following error:

> Call to undefined method App\Animal::getAnimalDateAttribute()

I have models like Animal and AnimalDate and I want to show response in json like bellow so I used Eloquent Resources with JsonResource:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Gilda Lynch",
  "country": "MO",
  "description": "Soluta maiores aut dicta repellat voluptas minima vel. Qui omnis assumenda maxime.",
  "image": "http://www.abshire.com/",
  "dates": [
    {
      "id": 6,
      "date_from": "2019-11-25 04:03:44",
      "date_to": "2019-09-30 05:47:28",
      "animal_id": 1,
    },
  ]
}
```

I think that problem is in a relationship between Animal model and AnimalDate model, but I can't fix it so I'm looking for help.

Relationship between these models: Animal hasMany AnimalDate

```php
class Animal extends Model
{

   public function animalDates()
   {
      return $this->hasMany(AnimalDate::class);
   }
}
```

and AnimalDate belongsTo Animal

```php
class AnimalDate extends Model
{
    public function animal()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Animal::class);
    }
}
```

I created Resources - AnimalDateResource.php

```php
class AnimalDateResource extends JsonResource
{
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return parent::toArray($request);
    }
}
```

and AnimalResource:

```php
class AnimalResource extends JsonResource
{
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        // return parent::toArray($request);
        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'name' => $this->name,
            'country' => $this->country,
            'description' => $this->description,
            'image' => $this->image_url,
            'dates' => AnimalDateResource::collection($this->animalDates)
        ];
    }
}
```

In controller I'm just using `new AnimalResource($animal)` and mehods index and show works perfect.

Is there any solution to POST it like Animal and then AnimalDate, or do I have to POST it first and than show relationship via JsonResouce?

Comment: the error that somewhere in your code you access ->animaleDate withouth plural, but no code here shows that, can you do a lookup in your project?

Comment: Not sure if related, but you have both animalDate and animalDates (pluralised)

Comment: you need to make an variable that can hold the array e.g. **newAnimalDates** the make a foreach loop and push each AnimalDates to your newAnimalDates array. Then you can call `'dates' => newAnimalDates`

Comment: share full error with screenshots and share full model class of `Animal`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so the problem was in AnimalController@store.

Before solution:

```php
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $data = $request->all();
    $animal = Animal::create($data);

    return response()->json($animal, 201);
}
```

After problem fixing:

```php
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $data = $request->all();
    $animal = Animal::create($data);

    // THIS LINE
    return new AnimalResource($animal);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access the relationship directly to you resource if it is **One to One**. But I dont know if you can access the relationship if it is **Many to One**. This thing works for me.

```
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        $newAnimalDates = array();
        foreach($AnimalDates as $animalDates) {
          $newAnimalDates[] = [
            "id": $animalDates->id,
            "date_from": $animalDates->date_from,
            "date_to": $animalDates->date_to,
            "animal_id": $animalDates->animal_id,
          ]
        }  

        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'name' => $this->name,
            'country' => $this->country,
            'description' => $this->description,
            'image' => $this->image_url,
            'dates' => $newAnimalDates
        ];
    }
```

Comment: i do not believe this is the problem he is facing

Comment: is the problem in his controller or resource or model?

Comment: That's not solution for my problem, I want to POST Animal first and than AnimalDate.

Comment: do you have the same field of **Animal** and **AnimalDates** in your form?